# Storing Multiple 2D Arrays in a Single Pandas Dataframe or xray

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to store multiple 2D ndarrays of different dimensions in a single Pandas dataframe, save that dataframe as a .csv, and load the .csv and retrieve the 2D arrays. I have seen ways of storing a single 2D array and ways of storing multiple 1D arrays, but never multiple 2D arrays. I would accept an answer using the xray package if necessary.

```
Nx = 10
Nz = 20

N_one = np.random.rand((Nx, Nz))
N_two = np.random.rand((Nx+1, Nz+1))
```

I have tried using a dictionary to store the arrays but I get back an error that says that it only supports 1D arrays.

```
my_dict = {"N_one": N_one, 'N_two': N_two}
dict_df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(value) for key,value in my_dict.items()})
```

For a single 2D array, this is how I would store one of the arrays in a dataframe and export it to a .csv

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(N_one)
test_df.to_csv('testdataset.csv',index=False)
```

Then I would read the .csv like this

```
location_of_dataset = r'C:\Users\User\testdataset.csv'
new_test_df = pd.read_csv(location_of_dataset)
```

Comment: How do you expect the 2 arrays to be arranged in the dataframe?  In the csv?  Remember both operate on a simple table model - rows with a consistent number of columns.  Your arrays have different numbers of columns.  Do you want an frame/csv with `Nz+1` columns, and filler values for the `N_one` rows?  Or `Nz` columns, and truncated columns ofr `N_two`?

Comment: I was implicitly assuming that I would have a dataframe of (Nz + Nz + 1) columns and (Nx + 1) rows where the first array would have a filler/NaN value for the last row

Comment: I haven't used them, but I believe there's some sort of `pandas` join/concatenate function(s) that can handle different numbers of columns.